Well line noise (air/ water) through house and searching for solution
I have been researching solutions for years but wondering if there is something I can install that diverts air from my well line before all that air runs through my house.
Situation:  Well head is >30" elevation up my driveway.  Well comes into the house and runs through all of the main floor into a large storage tank in a crawl space on the other side of the house.
Often, when the cistern pump calls for water pump to fill, we can hear air/ water coming through that line (it is very distracting!).  Normally, I suppose this would not be heard if the well line came directly to the holding tank from the other side of the house where the tank is located. This can happen more often in summer when there is less rain or drought.  I was thinking that some solution using a bladder tank of some kind where well line feed comes in bottom, flows out bottom and air stays trapped, and expelled automatically would be a solution.  Kind of a pressured water system active air extractor.  Anybody have any ideas?
Further info as suggested.   This system has a submersable pump.  Well is just over 100' deep where it is fractured.  It has an an 8" casing to 18'.   I figured what I could do was put in a custom check valve at the cistern so when the well pump stops, it clamps shut as I was thinking water was just draining from the top of the the well down my steep driveway to the cistern, which as I said has the well line running through the house.   That actually improved things.   Generally, we don't hear water/Air coming through our system but it does occasionally .. it is noisy when that happens.

Simply fixing the unspecified pump system so it's not sucking air every time it starts should do. Replace a foot valve or check valve, or replace a surface pump with a submersible pump...that's a subtle hint to [edit] and give details and/or pictures of the pump being used here.

Thanks for the comments.  I have added more info.
